# what enctype do I choose to keep option value as an object and keep the support type app/json?

Tags: html, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates

I am trying to send the value of an option as an object in a POST form, So I am using enctype='text/plain' to get an object instead of string. At the same time the supported media type is 'application/json'

Here the template:

```
    <form class="" action="/api/meal_planner/" method="post" enctype='text/plain'>
{% csrf_token %}

<h3> Starters </h3>

{% for food in foods %}
  {% if food.type == 'starter' %}
    <div id="f{{ forloop.counter }}">
      <h3> {{ food.display_name }} </h3>
      <div class="details">
        <ul>
          <li>calories: {{food.cal}}</li>
          <li>carbs: {{food.carbs}}</li>
          <li>carbs: {{food.carbs}}</li>
          <li>fibers: {{food.fibers}}</li>
          <li>proteins: {{food.proteins}}</li>
          <li>lipids: {{food.lipids}}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="image">
        <img src="{{food.imgUrl}}">
      </div>
    </div>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

<div class="select">
  <select name='starter'>
    {% for food in foods %}
      {% if food.type == 'starter' %}
    <option value='{"display_name":"{{food.display_name}}","cal":{{food.cal}}}'>{{ food.display_name }} </option>
    {% endif %}
  {% endfor %}
  </select>
</div>
```

Option as you see is :

```
<option value='{"display_name":"{{food.display_name}}","cal":{{food.cal}}}'>{{ food.display_name }} </option>
```

So I can have the body like this :
[Body of POST](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4nqD.png)

And this the Django API :

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def FoodResponse(foodData):
    try:
        #defining variables
        calMoy=500
        percentage=0.1
        calSum=0
        donnee = json.loads(json.dumps(foodData.data))
        print (donnee)
        calSum= calSum + donnee["starter"]["cal"]+ donnee["dish"]["cal"]+ donnee["desert"]["cal"]
        if ( (calSum < calMoy*(1-percentage)) or (calSum > calMoy*(1+percentage)) ):
            return JsonResponse({
            "status": "KO",
            "food": donnee
            })
        else:
            return JsonResponse({
            "status": "OK",
            "food": donnee
            })
    except ValueError as e:
        return Response(e.args[0],status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

And this the error :

[Error unsupported media type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FFfm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Django Rest Framework allows requests of `application/json` or `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default, and unless you write your own `text/plain` parser (there is an [example in the docs](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/parsers/#example)), the `text/plain` request will be rejected.

**However, I would advise you not to try and do this.** Rather than trying to send JSON as the value of each select option in the form using plain text encoding, it would be much more sensible to use the primary key of each `Food` object, and then lookup the `Food` object in the view using the primary key. Once looked up, you can retrieve the calories and any other data.

So in the form, remove the `enctype="text/plain"` and modify how you build the drop down to use the `Food` primary key:

```
<select name='starter'>
    {% for food in foods %}
        {% if food.type == 'starter' %}
            <option value="{{ food.pk }}">{{ food.display_name }} </option>
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

Do the same for the other dropdowns for dish and desert.

Then modify the view to something such as this:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
def FoodResponse(request):
    try:
        #defining variables
        calMoy=500
        percentage=0.1
        calSum=0

        # Lookup the food objects up using the primary key
        starter = Food.objects.get(pk=request.POST['starter'])
        dish = Food.objects.get(pk=request.POST['dish'])
        desert = Food.objects.get(pk=request.POST['desert'])

        # Retrieve the calories and calculate the total
        calSum= calSum + starter.cal+ dish.cal + desert.cal

        ...
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but the problem here is that I am dealing with a DB of foods without a primary key and you can't differentiate between food object even by name. So I have to send the required data as JSON. 
By the way I found a solution but it's a bit "unPro" and I am looking to make it even better